# MVC Razor read only TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In a MVC 3 Razor Project, I have defined `DisplayFormat` in ViewModel to format a DateTime Property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Posted Date")]
public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
```

And I need to make the field Read Only in View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostedDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

But when displaying the date in `TextBoxFor` it does not apply the DisplayFormat. If I Change `TextBoxFor` to a `EditorFor` DisplayFormat is applied but can not apply the readonly CSS property.

How to apply the date formatting & make the text box readonly?

Comment: are you getting the TextBox when editor for renders

Comment: Nalaka, have you tried using HtmlProperties notation? (Check the link on the answer, its breaking here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can still use editor for when the editor for renders I believe based on your case it should still render to the text-box after it renders you can use a simple jquery function to add an attribute read-only to the rendered text-box

```
$("#PostedDate").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

not sure if it the best solution but you can try it

Comment: The downside of this solution is that it only enforces the read-only property on the client-side, which can be manipulated by clever users in order to change the data in that field before submitting the updated data back to the server.